# Why do I need `Ctrl-c` when `curl` to the this tcp proxy

Tags: python, sockets, curl, proxy

I'm trying to get [this tcp proxy](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/114642-pinhole/) to work.  I used a simple server based on `BaseHTTPServer`

1. run server on port 12343
2. run proxy on port 12344
3. run curl against port 12343.  It works!
4. run curl against port 12344.  Now I need to press `Ctrl-C`.

[Here is the code](https://gist.github.com/zjiekai/bef84dbc21276d504533) and how to reproduce the situation:

```
$ ./server0.py  12343

$ ./relay.py 12344 127.0.0.1 12343

$ curl 'http://localhost:12343' # This works fine

$ curl 'http://localhost:12344' # This needs Ctrl-c
```

PS: Another question is how can I stop `relay.py` once it's running.  `Ctrl-C` does not work. Currently, I'm using `Ctrl-z` with `` kill `jobs -ps` ``

Comment: I guess because the HTTP connection isn't closed by the server?

Comment: @adarsh I agree but I do not know where should I close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because you forgot to close the connection between the client (curl) and relay.

The BaseHTTPServer will close the TCP connection once it finishes writing response, so it works fine to directly connect to the HTTP server.

When connecting to HTTP server through the relay, however, connections will like this

```
                   --Relay-------
                  |   pipe1     |
      connection1 | ----------> | connection2
    | ----------->|/           \|------------> |
curl|             |             |              | HTTP Server
    | <-----------|\  pipe2    /|<------------ |
                  |  <--------- |
```

The connection2 will be closed by the HTTP Server, but connection1 won't, so curl will keep hanging.

To fix the problem, just call
    socket.shutdown()
on connection1, the revised PipeThread.run() is like the following:

```
def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                data = self.source.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    break
                self.sink.send(data)
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(e)
                break
        logging.info('%s terminating' % self)

        self.sink.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR) #close the socket on the write side

        PipeThread.pipes.remove(self)
        logging.info('%s pipes active' % len(PipeThread.pipes))
```

Full code is revised code is [here](https://gist.github.com/leolee192/398c5f09ffcf7126d1b1)